# Javascript - Check if key exists in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a object in Javascript to parse the uri contents and attach their key / value pairs to it. However, I'm stuck on how to find out if a key exists. Here's the code :

```
var uri = {
    segments : {},
    parse : function() {
        var segments = {};
        var parts;
        var s;

        parts = location.href.split('/');
        parts = parts[3].split('?');
        parts = parts[1].split('&');

        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            s = parts[i].split('=');
            segments[s[0]] = s[1];
        }

        uri.segments = segments;

        return segments;
    },
    segment : function(key) {
        if (uri.segments.length == 0)
        {
            uri.parse();
        }

        /* before was 'key in uri-segments' */      
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(uri.segments, key))
        {
            return uri.segments[key];
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    },
};
```

**edit** : full code

Comment: What's wrong with using `in`?

Comment: @amnotiam For example, imagine a key called `toString`. `'toString' in {}` is true.`

Comment: @RobW: By *uri contents*, I would assume that specific keys are used for the different parts. Unless perhaps it's going to separate out the querystring parameters into keys.

Comment: @yoda Your question's code is incomplete. How do you define `uri`? Is it an array, object, custom object, ... ?

Comment: @amnotiam querystrings can be user-defined.

Comment: Point was that is the querystring itself going to be parsed, or is it just going to be a bulk querystring segment added? Also you mentioned *inherited* keys. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @amnotiam by inherited I mean they will be dinamically added to the object, not previously declared.

Comment: @yoda The uri will **never** be parsed, because `uri.segments.length == undefined` (it is **not** an array). `undefined == 0` is false.

Comment: I see. So not *inherited* in an OOP sense.

Comment: @RobW Thank you, I failed to see that. Changed it to `segments : []` and it worked :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) method to check whether a key exists or not:

```
// hasOwnProperty from the objects prototype, to avoid conflicts
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(uri.segments, key);
//                                   ^ object      ^ key
```

Comment: It says the key doesn't exist, but If I call it directly it displays the right result.